# AWS IAM authentication logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am looking for authentication activities in the AWS IAM logs; I collected all the logs for this purpose, however, I am not able to locate any logs indicating authentication. I wonder if someone could help me with the search parameters. Also, I checked the API references here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html); however, I did not see any API which indicates authentication activities. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Amazon CloudTrail can [capture login attempts to the AWS Management Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-aws-console-sign-in-events.html).

All other types of **authentication happen with the actual API calls**. For example, if an Amazon EC2 `StopInstance` API call is made to AWS, the credentials are checked, permissions are checked to confirm that the credentials are permitted to make such a call, then the action is performed. Once again, Amazon CloudTrail keeps an **audit trail** of this API request and whether it was successful.

The authentication takes place with every API call, rather than authenticating first, then making API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable CloudTrail for monitoring API call https://aws.amazon.com/es/cloudtrail/

Answer (score 0):

CloudTrail records authentication activities for both successful and unsuccessful login. The link below should have all the details you need regarding log details:

[image: IAM Authentication Log example]
[Logging IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/cloudtrail-integration.html#iam-info-in-cloudtrail)